# VBA timestamp only when cell changes, not when blank

Tags: excel, vba, time

Good day all,

I know there are several similar posts floating around, but I can't quite seem to find one relating to exactly what I need here. The code provided is what I currently use and it works, but it has issues as well.

1. I need it to only check for changes if the cell isn't blank. I run into an issue where any cell that receives information, while it doesn't always change the timestamp because of the restrictions (works as intended), has to save the information I suppose? It makes putting data in very very slow as you have to pause for 1-2sec between each input.
2. Is there a better way to handle the If statement that excludes certain columns. Currently just have them listed individually.

For reference - I want when the cells are blank and a new Order is put in, to not update the username and timestamp, but later on if any information in columns that are note excluded is changed, then the two cells containing username and time are updated to Now().

Thanks for any assistance on this!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
 

    Dim ThisRow As Long
    ThisRow = Target.Row

    'protect Header row from any changes
    If (ThisRow = 1) Then

           Application.EnableEvents = False
           Application.Undo
           Application.EnableEvents = True
           MsgBox "Header Row is Protected."
           Exit Sub

    End If

    If Target.Column >= 1 And Target.Column <> 7 And Target.Column <> 20 And Target.Column <> 24 And Target.Column <> 26 And Target.Column <> 28 And Target.Column <> 29 And Target.Column <> 30 Then

        Dim sOld As String, sNew As String
        sNew = Target.Value 'Log the new value

        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            .Undo
        End With

        sOld = Target.Value 'Log the old value
        Target.Value = sNew 'reset new value

        If sOld <> sNew Then

            ' time stamp corresponding to cell's last update
            Range("AD" & ThisRow).Value = Now
            ' Choose between Windows level UserName or Application level UserName
            'Range("AB" & ThisRow).Value = Environ("username")
            Range("AB" & ThisRow).Value = Application.UserName
            Range("AB:AD").EntireColumn.AutoFit

        End If
         

        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If
    'Set timestamps based on status dropdown
   Dim G As Range: Set G = Range("G2:G5000")
   Dim v As String
   If Intersect(Target, G) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

   Application.EnableEvents = False
      v = Target.Value
      If v = "ARB" Then Target.Offset(0, 29) = Now()
      If v = "VGA" Then Target.Offset(0, 30) = Now()
   Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: In effect does that equate to checking that `sOld` isn't blank?

Comment: For 2) a `Select Case` statement would be neater I suppose.

Comment: @SJR I suppose that is possible.

Comment: Still having trouble with checking if sOld is blank, which I'd assume may be a solution.

Comment: Add a check `if len(sold)>0 then` before your `If sOld <> sNew` ?

Comment: I tried that, but I still run into the same issue. It seems like it has to pause to check or save the information before moving to the next cell still.